# jupyter notebook ipython widgets display as text

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

A colleague (and myself) are trying to write some python scripts to do some common calculation which will also need to be used by our other colleagues. In order to make these scripts easy to use we're creating a simple GUI using ipywidgets. However, these widgets aren't very stable, sometimes they display and work fine, but sometimes they don't show but display the object as text:

```
ToggleButton(value=False, description='Design choice 1', icon='che…
ToggleButton(value=False, description='Design choice 2', icon='check', tooltip='Description')
Button(description='Continue to assign input values', icon='check', style=ButtonStyle(), tooltip='Click me'
```

What we're trying to achieve is to setup an easy system such that our colleagues can easily use our scripts. To do so we'll ask them to install miniconda and after that run a batch file to install all the necessary software/packages (essentially using conda to install the list of packages from a file). However when I do this with my current setup this doesn't always work well.

In my notebook extensions:
[image: jupyter notebook]

Any idea how I can get a stable setup such that these extensions work well?

The current environment

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\
envs\myenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.11                   py36_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
astroid                   1.6.5                    py36_0
babel                     2.6.0                    py36_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h945400d_0
cftime                    1.0.0b1          py36h452e1ab_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h420ce6e_1
cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py36_0
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h029ae33_0
cryptography              2.2.2            py36hfa6e2cd_0
curl                      7.60.0               h7602738_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0
docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hfd66bb0_2
freetype                  2.8                  h51f8f2c_1
hdf4                      4.2.13               h712560f_2
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1
html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h047fa9f_0
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.7                      py36_0
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.3                      0
ipykernel                 4.7.0            py36h2f9c1c0_0
ipython                   6.2.1            py36h9cf0123_1
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0
ipywidgets                7.2.1                    py36_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0
jedi                      0.12.0                   py36_1
jinja2                    2.10             py36h292fed1_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h7636477_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4
jupyter_client            5.1.0            py36h9902a9a_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36h6d89b47_1
jupyter_contrib_core      0.3.3                    py36_1    conda-forge
jupyter_contrib_nbextensions 0.5.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h56e9d50_0
jupyter_highlight_selected_word 0.2.0                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_latex_envs        1.4.4                    py36_0    conda-forge
jupyter_nbextensions_configurator 0.4.0                    py36_0    conda-forge

kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h12c3424_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hd1c21d2_0
libcurl                   7.60.0               hc4dcbb0_0
libiconv                  1.15                     vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.6.1                h62daf8c_0
libpng                    1.6.34               h79bbb47_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                hd619d38_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                hb8ad9f9_1
libxml2                   2.9.8                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
libxslt                   1.1.32                   vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
lxml                      4.2.2            py36heafd4d3_0    conda-forge
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.0              py36h0e26971_1
matplotlib                2.1.1            py36h2062329_0
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hb41005a_1
mistune                   0.8.3            py36hfa6e2cd_1
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1
mkl_fft                   1.0.1            py36h452e1ab_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h9258bd6_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h8dc0fde_0
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0
netcdf4                   1.4.0            py36hbfe741f_1
notebook                  5.2.2            py36hc48260a_0
numpy                     1.14.5           py36h9fa60d3_0
numpy-base                1.14.5           py36h5c71026_0
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2o               h8ea7d77_0
packaging                 17.1                     py36_0
pandas                    0.23.1           py36h830ac7b_0
pandoc                    2.2.1                h1a437c5_0
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3ef6317_1
parso                     0.2.1                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h9de030f_0
pillow                    5.1.0            py36h0738816_0
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h60b8f86_0
psutil                    5.4.6            py36hfa6e2cd_0
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py36_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hd053e01_1
pyflakes                  2.0.0                    py36_0
pygments                  2.2.0            py36hb010967_0
pylint                    1.9.2                    py36_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36h785a196_1
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py36_2
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0
python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0
pytz                      2018.4                   py36_0
pywinpty                  0.5.4                    py36_0
pyyaml                    3.12                     py36_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36hfa6e2cd_1
qt                        5.6.2           vc14h6f8c307_12  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0
qtpy                      1.4.2                    py36_0
regex                     2018.06.21       py36hfa6e2cd_0
requests                  2.19.1                   py36_0
rope                      0.10.7           py36had63a69_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py36h672f292_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                39.2.0                   py36_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h763602f_0
sphinx                    1.7.5                    py36_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36hbbac3d2_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py36_1
sqlite                    3.24.0               h7602738_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0
tk                        8.6.7                hcb92d03_3
tornado                   4.5.2            py36h57f6048_0
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0
urllib3                   1.23                     py36_0
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1            py36he67d7fd_1
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36he5f5981_0
xlrd                      1.1.0            py36h1cb58dc_1
xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h1a4751e_0
yaml                      0.1.7                    vc14_0  [vc14]  conda-forge
zeromq                    4.2.5                hc6251cf_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h8395fce_2
```

The nbextensions:

```
python-markdown/main enabled 
  jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled 
tree section
  nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled 
config dir:
C:\Users\906994\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\waterbouw2\etc\jupyter\nbconfig
notebook section
  nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled 
  contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main enabled 
  jupyter-js-widgets/extension enabled 
tree section
  nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled
```

config dir: C:\ProgramData\jupyter\nbconfig
    notebook section
      nbextensions_configurator/config_menu/main enabled 
      contrib_nbextensions_help_item/main enabled 
    tree section
      nbextensions_configurator/tree_tab/main enabled

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example of the GUI code you are using? The code section provided above isn't complete, some text has been truncated etc.

Comment: What you see above is not the code I have been using, it is what is shown on screen when I call display(widget). I had one conda environment, I've exported that to a file to make a second environment. In the first environment it shows the widgets in the second only the code above. My question is: how can I set up my environment such that I don't get these problems?

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue, it resolved after restarting the kernel and refreshing the browser page.